# linux + tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified

Tags: linux, terminal, redhat-enterprise-linux

I use in my bash script the tput command in order to colored the text

as 
tput setaf 2

when I run the script from putty or console every thing is ok

but when I run some external WIN application engine that run the script via SSH the we get the following error on tput

```
tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified
```

please advice what need to set ( ENV or else ) in my bash script in order to use the tput command ?

what value need to set for $TERM ( in my bash script ) ?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the library or application your Windows application uses, your best guess would be to set the TERM variable to `xterm`:

```
export TERM='xterm'
```

If that doesn't give you the desired results, refer to the manual of your library/application and find the terminal emulation type there.